# XCode Build fails with rsync error: "rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP"

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, rsync

When i try to run clean build with xcode 12.5 build fails with rsync error as below

```
rsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-55/rsync/rsync.c(244) [sender=2.6.9]
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

When further look into the error it mostly fails when rsync is trying to copy resource files or .sh files from installed pods.

Any inputs on resolving this would be appreciated.

Comment: `brew install rsync` fixed my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Run;

```
npx install-expo-modules
```

Should resolve all Expo module's build-time errors.